# How to lock the orientation with Sencha-touch?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins

My environment are used the Sencha-touch & PhoneGap. May I lock the orientation with Vertical. I don't want the user use the horizontal direction for operation.

```
launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('ebook.view.Main'));
},
```

I need add some control or config on lunch function? or I need Add the control to main.js.  My purpose is I want to lock the orientation on "vertical direction".  Have anyone can help me. thank you.

Other Reference: 
I found the below code on "package.json", I try to delete the "landscapeLeft"&"landscapeRight" and rebuild it got the same result. I can't lock the user orientation.

```
    /**
 * @cfg {Array[String]} orientations
 * @required
 * This is orientations that this application can run.
 */
"orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",
    "portraitUpsideDown"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do that in PhoneGap's config.xml

```
< preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 2):

On Android and using Phonegap 3.3 the orientation preference in config.xml seems to get ignored. One workaround that worked for me was to modify AndroidManifest.xml and add the attribute android:screenOrientation="portrait" to each activity tag. Seems to work.

Comment: But there is only one activity when we make use Apache cordova. So writing this will lock the whole app in portrait? Is it possible to lock a single screen in portrait?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which platform you are developing on. My experience with Sencha+PhoneGap is mainly on iOS.

Since all the web content generated by Sencha will be wrapped inside a view controller (which is the mechanism of phonegap project). You can simply lock the orientation by removing all the landscape option in your project's .plist.

It works fine in one of my demo.